# Column calculation based on previous day with parameters MDX

Tags: dynamic, comparison, mdx

I am trying to create a calculated column called "Percent Change vs. Yesterday" in SSAS MDX for implementation into an SSRS report. Basically I want find the percent change by day by area. So if the Area = Area then determine the percent change compared to the the previous day. There will also be a date selection parameter hopefully dynamically guiding what is visible

Line    Area      Date     Percent Correct **Percent Change vs Yesterday**

Line1   Arizona  6/1/2017   0.95
Line1   Arizona  6/2/2017   0.91
Line1   Arizona  6/3/2017   0.88
Line2   Virginia 6/1/2017   0.96
Line2   Virginia 6/2/2017   0.95

Comment: What have you managed to achieve so far?

Comment: do you have future dates in your cube's date dimension? do you have a marker in the cube so you can easily find today and yesterday?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the report will always include Date, you can use [PrevMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/prevmember-mdx) on the date hierarchy to get the previous Date, then use [Sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/sum-mdx) to get the numeric value of the relevant measure for that Date. The MDX for a Percent Change vs Yesterday calculation would look something like this:

```
(MEASURES.[Value] - SUM([Time].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.PREVMEMBER, MEASURES.[Value])) / SUM([Time].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.PREVMEMBER, MEASURES.[Value])
```